# Duplicate Check of email field using php

Tags: php, mysql

i am new at php. i want to know that how i can add duplicate check on my email field.

```
function email_exists($email){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT email FROM student";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $results = $statement->fetchAll();
    foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
        if ($result['email'] == $email){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

i made this function and it works but i have a problem that when i update only name of my form.php and if the email remains same in the field it gives error. i want to know how i can solve this problem, if i only update name and not the email.

Comment: you have the user id of the user..u cn easily check with it. if email exists for other id's

Comment: i don't got it. send you my code. can you please fix it and then show me? i'll be thankful to you.

Comment: is it possible for you to get the user id of the user....if yes then i can answer your question

Comment: i don't know how to get user id. i am new in coding.

Comment: you are updating the record..on what basis you are updating

Comment: i just made a simple form for my practise. i use this query for update.

Comment: $query = "UPDATE `student` SET name= '".$name."',
          addr='".$address."',
          age='".$age."',
          contact='".$contact."',
          email='".$email."'
                       WHERE id= '".$id."';";

               
                 
  global $db;
     $db->exec($query);
     echo "News Edit Done";
}

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS count FROM student GROUP BY email HAVING count  > 0 ORDER BY count DESC;";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function email_exists($email){
     global $db;
     $query = "SELECT email FROM student WHERE email=:email";
     $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
     $stmt->execute();

  if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
       return true;
      } else {
       return false;
     }
  }
```

Comment: my code is long enough, can not posted here. do u have email i can send you please

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
// @param email, id of updating record 
function email_exists($email, $id){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT email FROM student WHERE id !=".$id;
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $row_count = $statement->num_rows;// get total number of rows
    if($row_count > 0)
    {
          // record exists 
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```